# syntax for nls model with breakpoint

Tags: r, regression, nls

So the [saga](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143394/help-constructing-a-simple-regression-model-with-a-breakpoint) continues...

So I am trying to fit the model
$$Runoff = \begin{cases}
\beta_0 + \beta_1Pcp & \text{if $(Ant + Pcp) < Thold$;}\\
\beta_2 + \beta_3Pcp & \text{if $(Ant + Pcp) \geq Thold$;}
\end{cases}$$
Where $Pcp$ and $Ant$ are observed variables, and $Thold$ and the other parameters are estimated. I do not think I can do this with the *segmented* package, as the breakpoint is not in the predictor variables, but I think I should be able to do it fairly simply as a non-linear least-squares regression? I am not so good with the nls syntax, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Because the two expressions on the right hand side are identical, the relationship between `Ant+Pcp` and `Thold` is irrelevant, leaving a standard linear model for `Runoff` in terms of `Pcp`. Most likely there is a typographical error: could you please fix it by editing the question? When you do so, consider giving information about the nature of the random component of `Runoff`, too, because that is crucial for applying any form of least-squares fitting.

Comment: I have updated the question - basically I expect a different linear  relationship depending on whether or not $Ant + Pcp$ reaches above an estimated threshold. For the initial pass assuming normal errors should be fine. Thanks. I think we have been around on a similar model before, I am obviously still struggling with my analysis.

Comment: you could try multivariate adaptive regression splines in `earth` package.

Comment: @forecaster Could you indicate how splines could be applied to this problem?  (It's not immediately evident how that would be done.)

Comment: Are you simply asking for R code / help w/ R code? Or are you asking if this type of thing can be done w/ NLS? Note that the former would be off-topic here, but the latter is on-topic. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Perhaps - for context - you could consider linking to your previous questions related to this data.

Comment: @Glen_b, [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143394/help-constructing-a-simple-regression-model-with-a-breakpoint) is a link. Re: that post I re-thought my analysis and realized I could do without the parameter C, which I hoped would simplify things, but it appears the approach may be the same either way.

Comment: @IcebergSlim the link wasn't for my benefit; I found the previous questions before I asked. I was suggesting you put it into your question for the benefit of other people trying to follow your post. Giving interested readers more context helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In general this is such a nasty problem that we shouldn't apply automatic optimizers like `nls` in `R`.**  However, it is easily solvable upon observing that the model is linear, and meets the assumptions of ordinary least squares (OLS) estimation, conditional upon the value of `Thresh`.  Therefore you can search for solutions reliably by systematically varying `Thresh` across a reasonable range of values.

---

**To illustrate,** I simulated some data of this form in `R` using the equivalent model

$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 I(x_2 \lt \tau) + \beta_3 x_1 I(x_2 \lt \tau) + \varepsilon$$

where $\beta_0, \ldots, \beta_3$ are the coefficients (but not the same as those in the question!), $I$ is the indicator function, $\tau$ is the threshold parameter, $x_1$ represents values of `Pcp`, $x_2$ represents values of `Pcp + Ant`, and $\varepsilon$ has a zero-mean Normal distribution of unknown variance $\sigma^2$.

Note that the (intercept, slope) parameters of the two lines are $(\beta_0, \beta_1)$ when $x_2\ge \tau$ and $(\beta_0+\beta_2, \beta_1+\beta_3)$ otherwise.

An estimate of $\tau$ is a value (which usually will not be unique) that minimizes the sum of squared OLS residuals.  This is equivalent to the maximum likelihood solution.  To show how challenging the problem of finding this estimate can be, I plotted the sum of squared residuals *versus* trial values of $\tau$.  The left-hand plot in the figure shows an example of this profile.  The optimal value of $\tau$ is marked with a vertical red dotted line.  Its jagged, locally-constant, non-differentiable pattern makes it almost impossible for nearly any general-purpose optimizer to find the minimum reliably.  (It could easily be caught in a local minimum far from the global minimum.  I applied `optimize` to this problem as a check, and in some examples that's exactly what happened to it.)

Given this estimate of $\tau$, the model is linear and can be fit via OLS.  This fit is shown in the right-hand plot.  The true model consists of two lines of slopes $\pm 1$ crossing at $(0,1)$ and the true threshold is $-1/3$.  In this dataset, $x_1$ and $x_2$ were nearly uncorrelated.  A strong correlation between them will make the estimates unreliable.

[image: Figure]

*Orange squares and blue circles distinguish the cases $x_2 \lt \tau$ and $x_2 \ge \tau$, respectively.  The two subsets of data are separately fit with straight lines.*

A full maximum likelihood solution can be obtained by replacing the sum of squared residuals by the negative log likelihood and applying standard MLE methods to obtain confidence regions for the parameters and to test hypotheses about them.

---

```r
#
# Create a dataset with a specified model.
#
n <- 80
beta <- c(1,1,0,-2)
threshold <- -1/3
sigma <- 1
x1 <- seq(1-n,n-1,2)/n
set.seed(17)
x2 <- rnorm(n)
i <- x2 < threshold
x <- cbind(1, x1, i, x1*i)
y <- x %*% beta + rnorm(n, sd=sigma)
#
# Display the SSR profile for the threshold.
#
f <- function(threshold) lm(y ~ x1*I(x2 < threshold))
z <- seq(-1,1,0.5/n)*2*sd(x2)                   # Search range
w <- sapply(z, function(z) sum(resid(f(z))^2))  # Sum of squares of residuals

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(z, w, lwd=2, type="l", xlab="Threshold", ylab="SSR",main="Profile")
t.opt <- (z[which.min(w)] + z[length(z)+1 - which.min(rev(w))])/2
abline(v=t.opt, lty=3, lwd=3, col="Red")
#
# Fit the model to the data.
#
fit <- f(t.opt)
#
# Report and display the fit.
#
summary(fit)
plot(x1, y, pch=ifelse(x2 < t.opt, 21, 22), bg=ifelse(x2 < t.opt, "Blue", "Orange"),
     main="Data and Fit")
b <- coef(fit)
abline(b[c(1,2)], col="Orange", lwd=3, lty=1)
abline(b[c(1,2)] + b[c(3,4)], col="Blue", lwd=3, lty=1)
```

Comment: @ whuber. Thank you, this will take me a bit to think about.

Comment: @ whuber. If I may, could you elaborate on the extension with MLE? I am in particular interested in confidence intervals around the threshold. Thanks for your time

Comment: The connection is this: whereas my code measures the goodness of fit in terms of $\sum_i(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2$, the negative log likelihood is $\sum_i((y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2+\log(2\pi)+\log(\sigma^2))/2$: there is a multiplicative factor of $1/2$ as well as an additive factor that depends on the error variance $\sigma^2$. There are standard ways to translate changes in the log likelihood into confidence intervals or regions.

Comment: This is looking pretty good so far, thanks for the help